# Go: хук на сокет для net/http.ListenAndServe

Tags: http, golang, hook, listener

Не подскажете пожалуйста, как можно предварительно изменить запрос перед тем как его получит сам HTTP сервер? Занимаюсь разработкой для микроконтроллеров. Раньше работало приложение на MQTT, но с развитием проекта потребовалось новое - менее нагруженное на память микроконтроллера и более стабильное решение. За основу было решено взять HTTP протокол но требуется его немного зашифровать. То есть клиент отправляет серверу не "GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n", а нечто более похожее на base64.

Так вот задача разобрать на лету запрос, преобразовать и отдать  нормальный запрос в ServeMux, который будет уже нормально обработан. Но вот незадача понятия не имею как это сделать на лету. Есть у кого-нибудь какое простое решение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, чего вы хотите, это какое-то извращение. Нужно шифрование - используйте HTTPS. Однако, вам повезло, что стандартная библиотека го умеет под такие извращения подстраиваться. Во-первых, вам понадобится собственный `net.Conn`:

```golang
type base64TCPConn struct {
    net.Conn
    io.Reader
    io.WriteCloser
}

func (conn base64TCPConn) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    return conn.Reader.Read(b)
}

func (conn base64TCPConn) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = conn.WriteCloser.Write(b)
    if err != nil {
        return n, err
    }

    err = conn.WriteCloser.Close()
    return n, err
}

func (conn base64TCPConn) Close() error {
    err := conn.WriteCloser.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return conn.Conn.Close()
}
```

Во-вторых, собственный `net.Listener`, выдающий эти `net.Conn`ы:

```golang
type base64TCPListener struct {
    net.Listener
}

func (l base64TCPListener) Accept() (conn net.Conn, err error) {
    conn, err = l.Listener.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return base64TCPConn{
        Conn:   conn,
        Reader: base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, conn),
        WriteCloser: base64.NewEncoder(base64.StdEncoding, conn),
    }, err
}
```

В-третьих, используете это вместе с `net/http.Server`:

```golang
mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello, World!")
})
srv := &http.Server{Handler: mux}

tcpL, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp4", &net.TCPAddr{
    IP:   net.IPv4(127, 0, 0, 1),
    Port: 8080,
})
// Check err.

srv.Serve(base64TCPListener{tcpL})
```

В-четвёртых, запускаете и тестируете:

```
$ echo $'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n' | base64 | nc 127.0.0.1 8080 | base64 -d
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Fri, 08 Jun 2018 10:15:23 GMT
Content-Length: 13
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Hello, World!
```

Пример целиком: https://play.golang.org/p/RP6OKgSSOhV.

Comment: Работает просто супер! Это очень хорошее решение! Протестировал на полную нагрузку (69шт МК atmega328) и получились отличные результаты!

Comment: @EugeneX Если вас устраивает ответ, не забывайте отмечать его как правильный, нажав галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: Ой... Простите пожалуйста. Просто на радостях забыл ))))